# generate css on demand but I get net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Tags: php, css, file-not-found

I was using php to generate css file on the fly. Thus my HTML contained the code:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/ap.css.php">
```

Because it was PHP, the browser (correctly) would not cache it. However, that causes unnecessary overhead for subsequent page visits as all the pages to use the same resulting CSS (although that might vary for different users).

I thought I might generate a regular CSS file only once on a 404 error. I assumed the client-side would cache it then. IOW I put in the HTML:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/ap.css">
```

... and then I wrote a 404 script that would cunningly invoke /ap.css.php indirectly.

My intention was the client would thus request it only once and use the cached result for all subsequent page visits, reducing page load and data usage (especially for mobile phones).

Now I can type in the ap.css file name on the address bar and sure enough, the 404 handler delivers the desired CSS output, but when using the link in the HTML it still gets aborted with that 404.

... so I tried putting in a special text/css header. Alas, that made no difference in giving the error message as per the title.

```
<?php
    header_remove(); // try to remove any file not found header that might have been queued
    header('Content-Type: text/css');
?>
```

**Is there any way this 404 abort can be disabled, or must I choose either generate the CSS over and over for every page access or to make it the same regular static CSS file for everyone?**

Comment: You should rather not misuse the 404 handler for that, but use proper URL rewriting specifically for that one particular URL.

Comment: `header_remove` won’t do what you want here, if you want to keep doing it using the 404 handler approach, then use `header` to explicitly set your own 200 OK status code.

Comment: And FYI, PHP by default does not set any proper caching headers, so at most your CSS would get cached properly here, when the browser requests your CSS for the _second_ time, because then the web server takes over again and delivers the static file, so that the web server configuration regarding caching directives becomes active. If you wanted this to be cached right from the _first_ request on already, then your PHP script would need to respond with appropriate caching headers as well.

Comment: Those are 3 very useful answers I added the OK status code in the header and immeduately the net ERR_ABORT disappeared and it started working, but was still not caching the css.

Comment: Then I added the cache control header but it still isn't caching. I shall play around with that a bit. For the first answer. It's mostly  about minimizing data usage for  site visitors using their cell phone, but also it gives me the option of actually creating a customized ap.css file or letting it generate a default when there isn't one. My include scripts are in a separate directory tree outside the HTTP root (very safe) and are thus also common across multiple sites that use the same php engine. It gives a default configuration to all.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a step back and look at the actual problem:

- You want to generate CSS using PHP
- You don't want the browser to re-request it every time it loads a new page

The solution to this problem is **caching**.

You seem to be trying to get the effects of caching by using `.css` in the URL, but HTTP servers generally set "cache me" rules for *static files* and "don't cache me" rules for *dynamic files* no matter what the URL looks like.

You should just go back to the beginning where you have a simple PHP program, with `.php` in the URL, and then output cache control headers from your PHP.

There is an [excellent caching tutorial](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) which I recommend you read in order to determine what caching rules are best for you.

```
header("Cache-Control: max-age=86400");
```

… is likely suitable "Cache for 1 day".